# I prefer doing something to . .

Tags: sentence-construction

I've made the following sentence:

> I prefer doing things alone to with someone else.

Is that sentence correct? I also tried to replace that ***someone else*** with big company as follows:

> I prefer doing things alone to in a big company of people.

I tried to say that If I had a choice to join to a group of people and do the things with them I wouldn't do that and do the things myself.

Is it correct ot say so?

Comment: @Catija It was mispelling in the title. Yes, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the construction

> I prefer ... to ...

but the two clauses in the middle both need a similar construction (in this case, they both need a verb).  In order to make the sentence correct, you would need to add a verb to the second clause:

> I prefer doing things alone to **doing them** with someone else.

It's a little more wordy, but conveys the meaning much better and more correctly.

Comment: What about the big comapny?

Comment: It would be exactly the same:  "I prefer doing things alone to **doing them** in a big company of people."  (Although "a big group" might be a little more colloquial than "a big company").

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing things alone to with somebody else.

The sentence doesn't sound natural; you can rephrase it as follows:

I prefer doing things alone to doing (them) with somebody else. Alternatively, it will sound more easy on the ear if you say:

I prefer doing things alone rather than with somebody else. Please look up the word prefer under translations - The Free Dictionary.

Moreover, in informal English, you can say:

I do things alone rather than with somebody else.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prefer